# finding nearest neighbors at two different level

Tags: python, pyspark, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataframe which contains information at two levels g and c level. I want to impute missing values of the third column.

```
c1 - g1 - null;
c2 - g2 - -120;
c1 - g3 - -90;
c1 - g4 - -76;

g1 neighbours ---> g2, g3
```

in this example, I want to impute missing value in the first row third column. g1 has neighbors g2 and g3, but only g2 is connected with c1. Hence in this case the missing value of the first row will be -90.

```
c1 - g1 - null;
c1 - g2 - -120;
c2 - g3 - -90;
c1 - g4 - -76;

g1 neighbours ---> g2, g4
```

In this case, both g2 and g4 are neighbors of g1 and both are connected with c1, then the missing value would have been 98 as I am taking the mean of the neighbors ((-120-76)/2) which are connected with the c1. How can I implement this in the most efficient way in Python using Pyspark.

Comment: How do you detect the neighbours?

Comment: @werner I am detecting neighbors through a lib called geolib.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my question... how can we see from the example data which of the entires are neighbours?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.